# Jekyll collection permalinks show config variables in url

Tags: collections, jekyll, permalinks

Im using jekyll collections and for some reason permalinks are literally showing like this:

```
localhost:4000/my_collection/:title
```

Heres the code in my _config.yml

```
collections:
  my_collection:
    output: true
    permalink: '/:collection/:title'
```

Any ideas why it isn't pulling the title from front matter?

Comment: Better to show your code. Any repository url ?

Comment: They said its a bug :( https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3313#issuecomment-70312615

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say if it's a bug without tracking the issues, it seems this bug has been solved, however, the following produces the expected result for me. In my case I've just placed a `/` at the end of the permalink structure style..

So instead of

`permalink: '/:collection/:title'`

you could set it as

`permalink: '/:collection/:title/'`

I hope it helps.